# Why is Time.beginning_of_day not working in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently moved some code from my seeds.rb into my controller. In seeds.rb the code works.

```
# for each day create the time slots.
start_time = Time.beginning_of_day
end_time = start_time.end_of_day
```

`Time.beginning_of_day` is giving me a NoMethodError. I'm mystified. Based on the Rails Guides all of ActiveSupport is loaded in a Rails app. Can you tell me why it isn't working in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the method for an instance of the class.

```
Time.now.beginning_of_day
```

Comment: +1 `Time#beginning_of_day` is an [instance method](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Time/beginning_of_day).

Comment: Great question. It doesn't work. (Checked again for my own sanity.) How did the data get in my db? Thanks for the help!